# Is there any way/tool to see what is currently in the Clipboard?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, clipboard, developer-tools

I'm familiarizing myself with Clipboard API in the browser. Now I thought it might be helpful if I could actually see what is currently in the Clipboard. Maybe extension for Developer Tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the clipboard data via the [Clipboard API events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData), using `event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`. You can't access it via the `window` object (except in IE), due to the huge security risk of being able to access and modify the clipboard without the user knowing.